# Wrong version taken in apt command in EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt, apt-get

We are trying to install `libmysqlclient-dev` and used this command:

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev -y`

We got the following error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient21
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient21
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,892 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient21 amd64 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient21 amd64 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient-dev amd64 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient-dev amd64 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/libmysqlclient21_8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

We used both `apt-get update` and the `--fix-missing` option. We got the same error.

We then listed the available versions using `sudo apt-cache policy libmysqlclient-dev`:

we got:

```
libmysqlclient-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
  Version table:
     8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

We went to `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/` :
[image: Screen shot of the available packages]

We got the version of linux using `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

We then tried to force install the available version using `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev=8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 -y`:

We got :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.4' for 'libmysqlclient-dev' was not found
```

How do we get this package installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

1] edit your /etc/apt/sources.list

2] comment or delete all content

3] paste this

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
#
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
#
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

4. apt clean all && apt update

they are official packages of focal.
I hope it works!